# The youtubedl logger class

Tags: python, class, youtube-dl

I am very confused about how youtube-dl's logger class works in python and how it can be used to aid in debugging, raising warnings and error messages. Here's my following attempt at creating a logger class:

```
 class BuiltInLogger:

    @staticmethod
    def debug(msg):
        print(msg)

    @staticmethod
    def warning(msg):
        print(msg)

    @staticmethod
    def error(msg):
        print(msg)
```

I did it this way because I assume that youtube-dl creates an instance of the class whenever needed and prints out a specific message according to what error may have occurred. Please let me know if this is a good implementation of the logger class or what I can do to improve it, thanks!

Comment: why do you `print` is within method? why not `error = print` i mean?

Comment: @rv.kvetch I believe the youtube-dl api takes in an instance of this class and picks one of these methods depending upon the type of error or error-handling error available. I choose to print whatever message that may occur as a result.

Comment: oh ok, thats cool. yeah I think it's nice idea. I would also check out `logging` module which will print out level name (like info, warning, etc.) I think it would be nice improvement actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest as rewriting class as follow:

```py
class BuiltInLogger:

    # or maybe:
    #   debug = warning = error = print
    debug = print
    warning = print
    error = print
```

Usage:

```
>>> BuiltInLogger.debug('hey', 'whats up')
hey whats up
```

#### Example  with `logging` module

```py
import logging


# set minimum level you want be printed
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')

BuiltInLogger = logging.getLogger('some-module')
# (optional) set minimum level for logger only
BuiltInLogger.setLevel('DEBUG')

BuiltInLogger.debug('hey %s', 'whats up')
# DEBUG:some-module:hey whats up
```

Comment: That makes sense but is that how youtube-dl api wants it?

Comment: honestly not sure, i've used youtube-dl but not the api before :\

Comment: Okay sounds good, I'll also look into the logging module, thank you!

Comment: @RohanWalia I added simple example with `logging` module also